# Python Logging Config

Tags: python, logging, yaml

I'm trying a simple setup with python logging using the json format.  I've copied some config data from the logging config tutorial but when importing it I get:

```
(env) pi@omni-demo:~/omni-reader $ python
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> import logging.config
>>> logging.config.dictConfig('logging.conf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 812, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 374, in __init__
    self.config = ConvertingDict(config)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

The logging.conf file is:

```
version: 1
formatters:
    simple:
        format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: ERROR
        formatter: simple
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
loggers:
    root:
        level: ERROR
        handlers: [console]
```

The error is non descriptive and I just can't figure out what is the problem as the example is very simple.  Can anyone assist please?

Regards,

Neil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 logging yaml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012123/python3-logging-yaml-configuration)

Comment: Your question can only be answered by "Yes, someone can assist" or "No, nobody can assist", neither of which is helpful. Instead of typing regards and your name (already provided by SO), you would do good to spent time on a programming related question, instead of what people can(not) do. You also don't describe what you found at line 374, that you don't understand, nor why you do both `import logging` and `import logging.config`. Apart from this the application of [tag:yaml] is inappropriate (just like [tag:ascii] would be, although there are only ascii characters in your `logging.conf`).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and pedantic answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the configuration from `logging.conf` using your YAML library of choice, and pass the resulting dictionary to `dictConfig()` like in this example:

```
import logging.config
import yaml

with open('logging.conf') as f:
    conf = yaml.safe_load(f)
logging.config.dictConfig(conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of the function says:

```
def dictConfig(config):
    """Configure logging using a dictionary."""
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
```

So your config needs to be a dictionary if it's a variable inside your code, or formatted [in this way](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format) if it's an external file (in this case use [fileConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig)).

Perhaps this answer will help you: [Where is a complete example of logging.config.dictConfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/where-is-a-complete-example-of-logging-config-dictconfig)